# How to fix "TypeError: cb is not a function" error for comparing passwords

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, bcrypt

I've been starting to add user authentication into my app and when adding the login route, i've been getting the error "TypeError: cb is not a function". I know it is coming from my login route as all my other routes work fine.

I have tried researching the issue and trying a few fixes that i've found but none have worked. So i'm starting to believe i've messed up somewhere and I can't find where.

Login Route:

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, function (err, user) {
        if (err || user == null) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect('/login');
        }

        if (!user.comparePassword(req.body.password)) {
            req.flash('invalidDetails', 'Wrong username or password!');
            res.redirect('/login');
        } else {
            req.session.userId = user._id;
            req.flash('loggedIn', 'User ' + req.body.username + ' has been logged in!');
            return res.redirect('/');
        }
    });
});
```

User Model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    bcrypt = require('bcrypt'),
    SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

UserSchema.statics.authenticate = function (email, password, callback) {
    User.findOne({ email: email }).exec(function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        } else if (!user) {
            var err = new Error('User not found.');
            err.status = 401;
            return callback(err);
        }
        bcrypt.compare(password, hash, function (err, result) {
            if (result === true) {
                return callback(null, user);
            } else {
                return callback();
            }
        });
    });
};

UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    var user = this;

    // only hash the password if it has been modified (or is new)
    if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

    // generate a salt
    bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function (err, salt) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        // hash the password along with our new salt
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
            if (err) return next(err);

            // override the cleartext password with the hashed one
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function comparePassword(candidatePassword, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function (err, isMatch) {
        if (err) {
            return cb(err);
        }

        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
};

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

I'm expecting it to compare the password with the password that has been entered into the login form with the password that is stored in the database and log in the user if the password is correct or redirect back to the login page with the invalidDetails flash message if the password is incorrect.

But what i'm actually getting is the "TypeError: cb is not a function" error when trying to login.

Comment: `if (!user.comparePassword(req.body.password))` You're not passing callback function in this line

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing a callback that's why.

If you want a promise based method you can write something like this

```
AuthSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword) {
const currentPassword = this.password;
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, currentPassword, function(err, isMatch) {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        resolve(isMatch);
    });
})
};
```

And now you can call that with await